# Combine splitted start and end time into one start and end time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to combine some rows to one row.

My current query provides the following:

```
ID   Name   Dept   Hours  Date         Start_time           End_time
---  ----   ----   -----  ----         -----------          ----------
1    John   01-A   4:45   10-18-2016   10-18-2016 06:00:00  10-18-2016 10:45:00
1    John   01-A   3:15   10-18-2016   10-18-2016 11:15:00  10-18-2016 14:30:00
```

I need a `select` statement to show this result:

```
ID   Name   Dept   Hours  Date         Start_time           End_time
---  ----   ----   -----  ----         -----------          ----------
1    John   01-A   8:50   10-18-2016   10-18-2016 06:00:00  10-18-2016 14:30:00
```

Comment: This is a pretty basic MIN, MAX type of aggregation with the exception of Hours. How do you come up with 8:50? That just doesn't add up no matter how I look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming this is what you mean by Like data .

```
Select ID, Name, DEPT, SUM(HOURS), DATE, MIN(START_TIME),MAX(END_TIME)
from table
group by ID, Name, DEPT, DATE
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `sum()` doesn't work on `time` values.

Comment: its working!.. i don't know why i was group start time and end time and that caused the issue

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the issue is adding the times together (I'm presuming that `hours` is a `time`).  Here is one method:

```
select id, name, dept,
       cast(dateadd(minute, 0, sum(datediff(minute, 0, hours))) as time) as hours,
       date,
       min(start_time) as start_time,
       max(end_time) as end_time
from t
group by id, name, dept, date;
```

This will format the output as a time.  You can reformat it to whatever format you like.

Comment: the hours column shows numbers of hours worked from start time to end end time.  I've tried the method above and that doesn't yield the result

Comment: @Veebster . . . I find it curious that you accepted an answer that doesn't seem to me like it would work.

Comment: The reason its working is the time i have shown in my example is already in hours and is displayed as varchar hence the sum does work.  I think its my fault i should have mentioned that the hours column is varchar.  My apologies for miscommunication